# Как получить значение «_smt»?

Tags: php, вконтакте

Как получить значение переменной `_smt` (а конкретнее - цифру - `timeSpent`) для POST запроса при постинге в вк?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотрите `var_dump($_POST);` в начале скрипта обрабатывающего эти данные.

Comment: @Visman это совет разработчикам на стороне ВК? =)

Comment: @Sergiks, а автор вопроса post запрос шлет в VK? :)

Comment: @Visman при постинге на стену ВК обращение идёт к скрипту с таким же именем, `al_wall.php`. И метка «вконтакте». Поэтому предпологаю. Но я не видел там параметра `_smt` в десктоп-версии: ![скриншот](http://i.imgur.com/Sox8oRT.png)

Comment: @Sergiks, тогда я не понимаю вопроса. Если автор сам данные отправляет в vk, то почему их не может взять у себя же из скрипта? О_о

Comment: @Visman вероятно, ТС хочет перехитрить ВКонтакт и постить на стену мимо api. Только там ещё хэш от секретов ВК, который не подобрать.

Comment: что за хэш от секретов? _smt то появляется то нет в запросе post... http://i67.fastpic.ru/big/2015/1010/7e/2df0abae1a3322a00a64c7d8b63a977e.jpg